# pytorch_lightning.ModelCheckpoint not saving model

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am implementing Temporal Fusion Transformer (TFT) using pytorch (2.0.1+cpu), pytorch_forcasting (1.0.0), and pytorch_lightning (2.0.8). When I run the trainer.fit, I get an error “Checkpoint ‘c:/…/checkpoints/best_model.ckpt’ not found. Please check the file path.”

Here is the code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_forecasting import TimeSeriesDataSet, TemporalFusionTransformer
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import SMAPE
from pytorch_forecasting.data import GroupNormalizer
from pytorch_forecasting.data.encoders import NaNLabelEncoder
from pytorch_forecasting.data.examples import generate_ar_data
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import os
import torch
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger


class TFTLightning(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(TFTLightning, self).__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=["model"])

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = SMAPE()(y_hat, y)
        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = SMAPE()(y_hat, y)
        self.log("val_loss", loss)  # Log the validation loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.03)
        return optimizer
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = SMAPE()(y_hat, y)
        self.log("test_loss", loss)  # Log the test loss
        return loss

# Setting up the logger
logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='logs/', name='my_experiment')

# Generate synthetic time series data
data = generate_ar_data(seasonality=10.0, timesteps=400, n_series=100, seed=42)

# Convert the data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the time series dataset
max_encoder_length = 60
max_prediction_length = 20
training_cutoff = df["time_idx"].max() - max_prediction_length
context_length = max_encoder_length
prediction_length = max_prediction_length

# creating TimeSeriesDataSet
training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    df[df["time_idx"] <= training_cutoff],
    time_idx="time_idx",
    target="value",
    categorical_encoders={"series": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True)},
    group_ids=["series"],
    time_varying_unknown_reals=["value"],
    max_encoder_length=context_length,
    max_prediction_length=prediction_length,
)
validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df, min_prediction_idx=training_cutoff + 1)
batch_size = 64

# Define data loaders
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)

# Define the Temporal Fusion Transformer (TFT) model
tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=0.03,
    hidden_size=32,
    attention_head_size=1,
    dropout=0.1,
    hidden_continuous_size=8,
    output_size=7,
    loss=SMAPE(),
    log_interval=10,
    reduce_on_plateau_patience=4,
    
)

# Configure ModelCheckpoint to save the best model based on validation loss
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    monitor="val_loss",  # Specify the metric to monitor (e.g., validation loss)
    mode="min",          # "min" for metrics where lower values are better, "max" for higher values
    save_top_k=1,        # Save the top 1 best models
    dirpath=checkpoint_root_dir_path,  # Directory where checkpoints will be saved
    filename="best_model",   # File name for the best model checkpoint
)

# Wrap the TFT model in a LightningModule
model = TFTLightning(tft)

# Define a PyTorch Lightning trainer with the ModelCheckpoint callback
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=10,
    gradient_clip_val=0.1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],  # Add the ModelCheckpoint callback
    default_root_dir=checkpoint_root_dir_path
)

# Train the model
trainer.fit(
    model=model,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader
)

# Saving the best model by specifying the checkpoint path
best_model_checkpoint = os.path.join(trainer.logger.log_dir, "best_model.ckpt")
if os.path.exists(best_model_checkpoint):
    # Test the best model using the ModelCheckpoint
    results = trainer.test(ckpt_path=best_model_checkpoint)
else:
    print(f"Checkpoint '{best_model_checkpoint}' not found. Please check the file path.")
```

While training the model, versioned directories (version_0, version_1, etc) are created in lightning_logs directory; the contents are hparams.yaml files with no content. best_model.ckpt is not found in these versioned directories.

In **init** of class TFTLightning, I added self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=["model"]) because I was getting an error (ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required).

**Environment**
**OS**: Windows 11
**IDE**: VS Code
**Python**: 3.10.2